# python multiprocessing with concurrent features

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am new to python and tried a lot of methods for multiprocessing in python with no such benefits:
I have a task of implementing 3 methods x,y and z. What I have tried till now is:

```
Def foo:
Iterate over the lines in a text file:
   Call_method_x()
   Result from method x say x1
   Call_method_y() #this uses x1
   Result from method y say y1
   For i in range(4):
   Multiprocessing.Process(target=Call_method_z()) #this uses y1
```

I used multiprocessing here on method_z as this is the most cpu intensive.
i tried this another way:

```
def foo:
  call method_x()
  call method_y()
  call method_z()
def main():
  import concurrent.futures
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
       executor.map(foo())
```

Which one seems more appropriate ? I checked the execution time but it was not much of a difference. the thing is that first method_x(), then method_y() and then method_z() should be implemented as they use the output from each other. Both these ways work but theres no significant difference of using multiprocessing with these two methods.
Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiprocessing.Pool from python, something like :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

with open(<path-to-file>) as f:
    data = f.readlines()



def method_x():
    # do something
    pass


def method_y():
    x1 = method_x()
    #do something


def method_z():
    y1 = method_y()
    # do something

def call_home():
    p = Pool(6)
    p.map(method_z, data)
```

First you read all lines in variable data. Then invoke 6 processes and allow each line to be processed by any of 6 process

Comment: what if I have nothing to iterate over ? like method_z() takes no argument or iterable

Comment: i am not sure if it will make sense , I would want some data to be multiprocessed on, probably if you could give an example, it will help!